# Installing Packages on ATOM for python (linter and autopep8)

Tags: python, pip, atom-editor, flake8, linter

I am trying to set up my environment for ATOM for python. I did this on my previous PC and didn't run into much trouble but this time I believe something is messed up and I don't know how to fix it.

**Linter-flake8 installation:**

I installed it by doing this:

```
settings --> install --> search packages --> linter-flake8 --> install.
```

Dependencies were installed afterward automatically.

then I ran the CMD and installed flake8 using:

```
py -m pip install flake8
```

When I try typing my code into ATOM; I get this error:

```
[Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: Failed to spawn command `flake8`. Make sure `flake8` is installed and on your PATH
at C:\Users\yazan\.atom…\lib\helpers.js:130
(anonymous) @   C:\Users\yazan\.atom…ter\dist\index.js:1
```

**Things I tried to fix this:**

1. Adding ATOM to my path, which I did but did not work (ATOM and
   Python both are in my user and system, environment variables)
2. Checking that my ATOM is running the same version of python.

> ```
> import sys
> print(sys.version)
> ```

```
3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

3. Checked installation path for my linter-flake8 in CMD:

result -->

```
C:\Users\yazan>py -m pip install flake8
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in c:\users\yazan\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (3.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 in 
c:\users\yazan\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from flake8) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes<2.4.0,>=2.3.0 in 
c:\users\yazan\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from flake8) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle<2.8.0,>=2.7.0 in 
c:\users\yazan\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from flake8) (2.7.0)
```

I am running out of ideas and searched a lot but could not figure out how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the linter-flake8 [README](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8#settings), you can set the `executablePath` in the package settings. This should help you get around Atom's flaky support for environment variables.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, so I would just go into the environment variables and add the above path to it?

Comment: No, it's the other way around: you add the full path to `flake8` to this setting (e.g. the result of `which flake8`)

Comment: I see! Much appreciated!